# Rewriting array in given order

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, function-definition

I need to rewrite an array in given order below:

> Write a void shuffle function (int* we, int count, int* wy) that rewrites the the elements of the we array (where the count parameter specifies the size of the we array) to the array wy according.

I tried with for loop to divide the array for i < 5 and i > 5 but all the time got some problems. The only one which work for now is rewriting element[0]. Any help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

void zadanie1(void)
{

    int count = 11;
    int* we = new int[count];
    int* wy = new int[count];


    cout << "Begin: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        we[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << we[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "End: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            wy[i] = we[i];
            cout << wy[i] << " ";
            i++;
        };
        
        
    };
}
```

Comment: Please provide all information in the question and do not use links to images.

Comment: Define "some problems".

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= count / 2; ++i) {wy[2 * i] = we[i];}` should do half of the pb.

Comment: I suggest to not use `rand` to fill your array, `iota` (i.e 0, 1, 2, .., n) seems simpler (and give result ;) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image, you see that you map the element `i->2*i` for `i=0...5`, and `i->2*i-11` for `i=6..10`. Thus the required loop is

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  wy[2 * i] = we[i];

for (int i = 6; i < 11; i++)
  wy[2 * i - 11] = we[i];
```

For a general size `count` the loop looks like

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (count / 2); i++)
  wy[2 * i] = we[i];

for (int i = (count / 2) + 1; i < count; i++)
  wy[2 * i - count] = we[i];
```

Comment: Great. So simple and working! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared the following way

```
void shuffle( const int *src, size_t n, int *dsn );
```

That is the first parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const` because the source array is not changed within the function and the second parameter should have the unsigned integer type `size_t` instead of the signed integer type `int`.

Within the function it is enough to write one for loop.

Here is a demonstration program. In the first compound statement there are used arrays with an even number of elements and in the second compound statement there are used arrays with an odd number of elements.

```
#include <iostream>

void shuffle( const int *src, size_t n, int *dsn )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, middle = ( n + 1 ) / 2; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if (i < middle)
        {
            dsn[2 * i] = src[i];
        }
        else
        {
            dsn[2 * ( i - middle ) + 1] = src[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        const size_t N = 10;
        int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int b[N];

        for (const auto &item : a)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        shuffle( a, N, b );

        for (const auto &item : b)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    {
        const size_t N = 11;
        int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11 };
        int b[N];

        for (const auto &item : a)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        shuffle( a, N, b );

        for (const auto &item : b)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 11 6
```